# Do you need to completely reinstall Ubuntu non-LTS every update?

Tags: updates

I was wondering if you need to reinstall Ubuntu everytime there is a new non LTS version or can you update it onto your installed version? I am new to Linux and I want something in between the LTS versions and the bleeding edge distros, so does the normal non-LTS version update automatically and you have to install it once like manjaro and every couple of months it updates to the new version or not?

Comment: You can upgrade from any release to the next one without reinstalling. But you cannot skip releases, except from LTS to next LTS.

Comment: No you don't need to re-install.  My own system was *artful* (called 17.10 on it's release, ie. the 2017-October release), and has been upgraded every six months since then....  It's not automatic; you have three months after the new release comes out (where non-LTS) to *release-upgrade* to it (ie. 9 months since initial release; the next release comes out 6 months later given you a three month window to decide when you want to *release-upgrade*). I'd say non-LTS is what you're after (myself I'm on *hirsute* or the *development* cycle, what will become 21.04 when released)